# Incorrect work of QDomNode namespace detection

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qt4, xml-namespaces

I'm working on the MIME type detector, and need to split various XML-files by their namespaces and root tag names.
I'm using Qt DOM API for XML: `QDomDocument`, `QDomNode`, `QDomElement` etc.
My test xml (extremelly simple):

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'KOI8-R'?>
<root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</root>
```

My C++/Qt code for load XML and understand it's namespace and root tag:

```
// _d is QIODevice object, XML data source
QDomDocument doc;
if (!doc.setContent (_d))
{
    qWarning () << "QDomDocument::setContent has failed on file";
    _d->close ();
    continue;
}

QDomElement root_item = doc.documentElement ();
qDebug () << "Namespace URI:" << root_item.namespaceURI () << root_item.localName () << root_item.prefix ();
```

In the output i get just three empty strings, including namespace one. But i expected `"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`.
Am i doing something wrong?

P.S. `root_item.tagName()` shows `root` as expected, i.e. XML file was parsed correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Lol, i just needed to add `doc.setContent (_d, true)`, where second parameter enables namespace processing. Hope this will be useful for someone else.